# Auto-increment counter with formatting in Millions, Billions etc (javascript)

Tags: javascript, counter, setinterval, auto-increment, infinity

I am trying to display an auto increasing counter till infinity. It should auto format into Thousand, Million, Billion, etc with up to 3 decimal places when it reaches those denominations.

Eg: 1234 should automatically show as 1.234 K (Preferable with prefix $)
123456 as $123.456 K
1234567 as $1.234 Million
1234567891 as $1.234 Billion
and so on (May be till Decilli Kindly adviceon, leaving room for further denominations)

I am using this for increment counter

```
var initial = 1;
var inc = 500;
$(document).ready(function () {
    go();
    setInterval(function () {
        go();
    }, inc);
});
function go() {
    $("#inccounter").html(initial.toFixed(0));
    initial += 1;
}
```

but i am unable to format it as it increases.

Comment: is your question, how to format or how to format while incrementing ?

Comment: Hi yes it is to continuously format while incrementing. Thanks

Comment: so do you have the code to format a given to desired output ?

Comment: I did try something but it ends up truncating the number when it reduces it to Thousands. So the counter never goes beyond 1K. Also, i can't get the decimal places.

Comment: well i will give you a very high level idea.. let the formating function be called `format` and let your value be stored in a variable `initial`.. you can just do  `.html(format(initial))` , doest that make sense ?

Comment: @ashishsingh thanks. I did try that. actually my problem is actual formatting whilst still retaining the last complete number so that it does not lose the last incremented value when it truncates the not needed numerals and suffixes the denomination to it. Because when the formatting function runs on the reduced value, it will not give accurate incremented value. I hope i am able to make you understand.

Comment: so `initial` variable should only hold the full number value and whenever you want to add to html you call `format` function, initial should not be affected

Comment: Could you tell me through little example with regards to my given code. Thanks

Comment: just assume format function does what you want, you can look at this jsbin http://jsbin.com/yejinuboyu/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks it worked. Oddly not with jquery I had to use `document.getElementById("inccounter").innerHTML = format(initial);`But Thanks really.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a string to display each time you want to update the number. Some useful snippets:

Figure out number of digits
digits = Math.floor(Math.log10(yourNumber))+1

Truncate
truncated = Math.floor(yourNumber*Math.pow(10, places))/Math.pow(10, places)